# How to fix the error exe exited with error code 0?

Tags: perl

I am working in perl. I executed a batch file which will run the exe file. I used PSExec command to run the exe file. But i am getting error as client.exe exited with error code 0. Why this error occurs and where i went wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: put on some code,which exe you are using,what things are inside batch script .mention  more details about scenario oyu are using

Comment: Huh? Error code `0` usually means *success*.

Comment: You have a Perl script that runs a batch script which uses PsExec to execute a exetubale on a remote machine? Imho something somewhere went wrong there.

Comment: `die` will always cause the process to exit with a non-zero status (`$! || ($? >> 8) || 255`)

Answer (score 4):

From the [PsExec documentation](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/psexec):

> Upon exit, a process specifies an integer that the process's parent process can read. Programs often use the exit code to report the success or failure of their execution. Whenever a process executed with PsExec is completed, PsExec displays the process's exit code and returns the exit code as its own exit code. You should test a program's behavior or check its documentation to determine what that program's specific error codes mean, but an exit code of `0` typically means success. The `-s` switch specifies that PsExec should execute the command under the System account.

So that is just the return value of the run exe file. And almost every app will return a `0` if everything went smoothly. So unless you have any other reason to believe something went wrong, i would assume your exe to have exited successfully.

And *if* you have reason to believe an error occured, you will have to check the documentation of your exe to find out what an exit code of zero means it its specific case. And if it means anything but success, write them an angry email, preferably.